# Redshift unexpectedly returns a null value for items not found in a sub-query

Tags: sql, null, amazon-redshift, notin

I have this query that's returning no results:

```
SELECT review_id
FROM review_table
WHERE review_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT review_id
    FROM review_migration_table
)
ORDER BY review_id
```

However, I expected it to return all `review_id`s that aren't in my migration table (I'm trying to identify all reviews that weren't migrated successfully). The reason I'm expecting non-null results is that I *know* there are reviews in `review_table` that aren't in `review_migration_table`:

```
SELECT
    review_id,
    review_id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT review_id
        FROM review_migration_table
        WHERE filter_column = 170938)
FROM review_table
WHERE
    filter_column = 170938
ORDER BY review_id ASC

 review_id | ?column?
-----------+----------
 127260864 | f
 130811274 |
(2 rows)
```

Why does Redshift return a "NULL" value for the 2nd record in this query? And, more concretely, how can I get my first query to return 130811274 (and other reviews) that are in `review_table` but *not in* `review_migration_table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of `a NOT IN(b, c)` to be equivalent to `NOT (a=b OR a=c)`. I think there is a NULL value in the `review_id` column of the review_migration_table table, so thus you have `NOT (a=b OR a=NULL)` which will either give `FALSE` if `a=b` or NULL if `a<>b`.  The easiest workaround here is probably to filter out NULL `review_id` from the `IN` list, e.g.:

```
SELECT
    review_id,
    review_id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT review_id
        FROM review_migration_table
        WHERE filter_column = 170938 and review_id IS NOT NULL)
FROM review_table
WHERE
    filter_column = 170938
ORDER BY review_id ASC
```

Comment: Yup - the unexpected `NULL` value was it. Thanks! (Now on to determine why there was a `NULL` value in there... =D)